# How to disable submit button and submit form using IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, web

So I'm using IE8, I have to submit a form and disable the button.  So I was going to use onclick to do this.  The problem is if I use onclick, it doesn't submit the form, so I would need to submit the form manually with javascript.  However, if I try to submit the form with javascript I get an access denied error due to ie8 'security'...

So, what's my best way of doing this?

Comment: can you post the code you tried?

Comment: you can use onsubmit handler to disable button

Comment: when you submit a form, do you need to go a specific page or just refreshed the page? Have you tried using php for submitting a form

Comment: @IlyaBursov yup. This has been asked and answered before http://stackoverflow.com/a/20157395/961695

Comment: To add to the suggestions, try onmouseup. But onsubmit is a better option.