# How to disable a button but still allow form submission in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, forms, google-chrome

We need to disable the button after a click to prevent it from being clicked again.

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click',
    function(e) {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    });
```

It works fine in Microsoft Edge. But in Chrome, the button is disabled and the form is never submitted. It seems that Chrome has an implicit `event.preventDefault()` when we mess up with the button.

How can we disable the button without preventing the form from being submitted?

Comment: Have you tried the `form Submit` event instead of `button click`event ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling a submit button when clicking on it , will prevent the form from being submitted on Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157321/disabling-a-submit-button-when-clicking-on-it-will-prevent-the-form-from-being)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the button click, you need to disable the button after the form submit. Depending on your setup, something like this...

```
$('#form').on('submit',
    function(e) {
        $(#btnSubmit).attr('disabled', true);
    });
```